# running github actions on push of a tag not executing

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm new to yml language and just setup a github actions flow which works well manually, however when I try to make it work on pushing of specific tag it doesn't work:

I'm trying to have the yml execute after doing

```
git commit -am "my commit"
git tag cicd11
git push
```

and my .yml starts with this:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - cicd**
```

I've read many questions on SO, but noone seems to be doing push on tags and this is supposed to be possible according to the manual.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after rereading the doc carefully as suggested by myz540, I realized that my yaml was correct what was needed is a `--tags` during push i.e.:

```
git commit -am "my commit"
git tag cicd11
git push --tags
```

That's it, the yaml stays the same:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - cicd**
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify the tag. Per docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore

`A tag named v2 (refs/tags/v2)`

So you can try `**cicd**` or `refs/tags/cicd**`

Comment: Actually it turns out `cicd**` was correct but I was specifying the tag incorrectly